# Redux Child Component from array.map not Re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux

So here is the flow of the components:

In the main component, I am getting the state from the redux store with useSelector hook.

```
const state = useSelector((state) => state);
```

I am rendering my button component and passing it the state to cause re-render:

```
<TalentButton
              imgSrc={Ferocity}
              talentName="FerocityToolTip"
              req="15"
              spec="1"
              maxPoints="5"
              playableClass="Hunter"
              state={state}
              parentTalent={["1"]}
              arrows={[
                {
                  arrowType: "downMedium",
                  color: "silver",
                  parentTalent: "1",
                  spec: "1",
                },
              ]}
              id="11"
            />
```

Inside the TalentButton component, it returns an array of Arrow Components in a map function. The problem is that the components inside this .map do not re-render even though the correct state is visible in react devtools.

```
{props?.arrows?.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Arrow
            arrowType={item.arrowType}
            parentTalent={item.parentTalent}
            childTalent={
              item?.childTalent !== undefined ? item?.childTalent : null
            }
            totalPoints={props.state.totalPoints}
            spec={item.spec}
            key={item}
          />
        );
      })}
```

Inside the arrow component, the color is dependent on the redux dev tools and chrome console, but it's not showing correctly until I force it to re-render with other ui actions.

[image: stateInChromeDevTools]

Here the arrow turns gold right after updating the state from another action:

[image]

I tried giving the useEffect inside the Arrow component state and props as dependencies but it's not working.

Arrow component:

```
export const Arrow = (props) => {
  const [arrowSource, setArrowSource] = useState(null);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("silver");
  const state = props.state;

  useEffect(() => {

    switch (props.spec) {
      case "1":
        if (props.parentTalent === "1") {
          console.table(state.spec1Arrows)
          setColor(state.spec1Arrows.spec1Req1Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "2") {
          setColor(state.spec1Arrows.spec1Req2Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "3") {
          setColor(state.spec1Arrows.spec1Req3Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "4") {
          setColor(state.spec1Arrows.spec1Req4Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "5") {
          setColor(state.spec1Arrows.spec1Req6Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "6") {
          setColor(state.spec1Arrows.spec1Req6Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "7") {
          setColor(state.spec1Arrows.spec1Req7Arrow);
        }
        break;
      case "2":
        if (props.parentTalent === "1") {
          setColor(state.spec2Arrows.spec2Req1Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "2") {
          setColor(state.spec2Arrows.spec2Req2Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "3") {
          setColor(state.spec2Arrows.spec2Req3Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "4") {
          setColor(state.spec2Arrows.spec2Req4Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "5") {
          setColor(state.spec2Arrows.spec2Req6Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "6") {
          setColor(state.spec2Arrows.spec2Req6Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "7") {
          setColor(state.spec2Arrows.spec2Req7Arrow);
        }
        break;
      case "3":
        if (props.parentTalent === "1") {
          setColor(state.spec3Arrows.spec3Req1Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "2") {
          setColor(state.spec3Arrows.spec3Req2Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "3") {
          setColor(state.spec3Arrows.spec3Req3Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "4") {
          setColor(state.spec3Arrows.spec3Req4Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "5") {
          setColor(state.spec3Arrows.spec3Req6Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "6") {
          setColor(state.spec3Arrows.spec3Req6Arrow);
        } else if (props.parentTalent === "7") {
          setColor(state.spec3Arrows.spec3Req7Arrow);
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }, [state, props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (props.arrowType) {
      case "downSmall":
        if (color === "silver") {
          setArrowSource(downSmallSilver);
        } else if (color === "gold") {
          setArrowSource(downSmallGold);
        }
        break;
      case "downMedium":
        if (color === "silver") {
          setArrowSource(downMediumSilver);
        } else if (color === "gold") {
          setArrowSource(downMediumGold);
        }
        break;
      case "downLarge":
        if (color === "silver") {
          setArrowSource(downLargeSilver);
        } else if (color === "gold") {
          setArrowSource(downLargeGold);
        }
        break;
      case "angleArrow":
        if (color === "silver") {
          setArrowSource(angleArrowSilver);
        } else if (color === "gold") {
          setArrowSource(angleArrowGold);
        }
        break;
      case "leftArrow":
        if (color === "silver") {
          setArrowSource(leftArrowSilver);
        } else if (color === "gold") {
          setArrowSource(leftArrowGold);
        }
        break;
      case "rightArrow":
        if (color === "silver") {
          setArrowSource(rightArrowSilver);
        } else if (color === "gold") {
          setArrowSource(rightArrowGold);
        }
        break;
      default:
        console.log("No matching arrow type, check your spelling.");
    }
  }, [state, props]);

  return (
    <img
      className={props.arrowType}
      src={arrowSource}
      alt={props.arrowType}
      id={`arrwReq${props.parentTalent}Spec${props.spec}`}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the Arrow component? so it can be easier to understand the conditions used for the color property

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani sure thing, I added that to the bottom.

Comment: Also would like to know how you are updating the redux store? where you expect your Arrow component to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Keys need to be consistent from render to render.

```
arrows={[
  {
    arrowType: "downMedium",
    color: "silver",
    parentTalent: "1",
    spec: "1",
  },
]}

.
.
.
{props?.arrows?.map((item) => {
  .
  .
  key={item}
}
```

This will create a new reference each render and may be preventing React from correctly updating the DOM element as it no longer has the same reference. I would suggest adding some ID's to those arrow data points and using them as values for your `key` prop instead.